# Switch between different Views in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I read a lot of questions / answers in the stack overflow community about switching between different ViewControllers but I couldn't find the correct answer for my specific problem.

1. I'm using a NavigationViewController to "connect" all my different viewControllers (ViewController / TableViewController / CollectionViewController)
2. I have got some classes which aren't depending on a ViewController class. For example to to calculate anything in my "calculate" class.

I'm searching for an easy solution, to switch between all my ViewControllers. And I would like to decide in my "calculate" class e.g. to go one step back in my Navigation ViewController.

In the moment I use this:

1. Example to switch between two different ViewControllers:

   ```
   let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StartPage") as! StartPageView
   self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

**PROBLEM: This example only works in a ViewController class and the navigation bar disappears.**

2. Example to go one step back in my NavigationViewController:

   ```
   self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
   ```

**PROBLEM: This example only works in a ViewController class.**

**EDIT 1:**

I found a nice solution to call all my viewControllers with this part of code:

```
    let switchViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as! ScanTableView
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(switchViewController, animated: true)
```

How can I call this code in a non ViewController class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the new view controller onto your existing navigation stack, rather than presenting it modally:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StartPage") as! StartPageView
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: This code works pretty well to switch from one ViewController to another! Now the navigation bar doesn't disappear. But I'm not able to use this code in another class than a ViewController class. I get the error message: "Value of type TEST_CLASS has no member 'storyboard'" Is there a possibility to fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: And there is another problem with your core. When I call it, the switch between the two ViewControllers works well but there is a new back button created. Is it possible to prevent that? I would like to restore the old ones.