# How to reload CollectionViewCells from another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I try to reload a CollectionView when receiving some BLE data. Here is my BluetoothManager Class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
static var bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
...
var Value: [String] = [""]
...
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?){
//For this example, there is only a string value to update
Value[0] = "It works!"
}}
```

Everything works fine, when I receive some data the `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` function is called and the first item of the Value array is the string "It works". Now I would like to refresh / reload my CollectionView controller, to display the new value. This is my Collection view class:

```
import UIKit

class ValueCollectionView: UICollectionViewController{
    @IBOutlet var ValueCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var valueCollectionViewCell: ValueCollectionViewCell = ValueCollectionViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.Value.count
    }

    override func collectionView(tableView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell: ValueCollectionViewCell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("valueCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ValueCollectionViewCell
        cell.ValueCollectionViewLabel.text = BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.Value[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

What do I have to add in my BluetoothManager class to reload the CollectionView? I thought about something like: `ValueCollectionView.reloadData()` but I don't know, how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
static var bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
...
var ValueCollectionView: UICollectionView? 
var Value: [String] = [""]
...
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?){
//For this example, there is only a string value to update
Value[0] = "It works!"
ValueCollectionView?.reloadData()
}}
```

and

```
import UIKit

class ValueCollectionView: UICollectionViewController{
    @IBOutlet var ValueCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var valueCollectionViewCell: ValueCollectionViewCell = ValueCollectionViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.ValueCollectionView = ValueCollectionView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.Value.count
    }

    override func collectionView(tableView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell: ValueCollectionViewCell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("valueCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ValueCollectionViewCell
        cell.ValueCollectionViewLabel.text = BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.Value[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: That works pretty good. Thank you so much! Maybe you can also solve this problem.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314396/switch-between-different-views-in-swift)

Comment: One question to your code. Why do I have to use an optional in this case : var ValueCollectionView: UICollectionView? ? You are completely right, when I write var ValueCollectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView() I get an error but why?

Comment: @Passe if peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic called before initialization UICollectionView, ValueCollectionView will be null